# Download a Word editable document from an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I currently have an aspx page returning a html form (with images and css). I would like get a download Word editable version of this form without rewrite all the code. Is it possible ?

An example : I Have a page 'WebForm2.aspx' with a simple content like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="WebApplication15.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myTest" Text="Doc 1" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myTest2" Text="Doc 2" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myTest3" Text="Doc 3" /><br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="myTest4" Text="Doc 4" /><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like that from an other page for example a button that lets you download the contents of 'WebForm2.aspx' in an editable Word document.

I Add this in Page_PreRender method

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
```

It's partially work. If I save the document css and images aren't loaded but if I only open the downloadable content css and images are loaded.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working (exception/error message) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word can edit html document so by adding Content-Type=application/msword record in header will make browser open your page in browser unfortunately without css and images.

Add following code in prerender event on your page

```
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
```

Comment: When I only open the downloadable content instead of save it, css and images are loaded. It's better that nothing but i've another issue. There are chechbox in my page and if user check this the state of checkbox is not present in the word document... Are you an idea ?

Comment: It was because the checkbox wasn't aspx checkbox but simply html